# How to setup a browse menu to cycle a page and it's sub pages only in typo3?

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I am trying to set up a browse menu to cycle a page and it's sub pages. I have to have it in the format of **< 2 >** where **<** is the previous page, **2** is the current page, and **>** is the next page. To reslove this I decided to put an extension template on the parent page which in which a browse menu points to the first page of the sub page tree:

```
lib.pagenumber = HMENU
lib.pagenumber{
  special = browse
  special.items = | next
  special.next.uid = 100
  special.next.fields.title = 2

  1 = TMENU
  1{
     noBlur = 1
     expAll = 0
     NO = 1
     NO.ATagTitle = 1
     NO.before = <div id="currLGMpg" class= "currpg">1</div>
     NO.linkWrap = <div class=nextLGMpg>|</div>

  }
}
```

The current page is not linked but just an image box which has to be between the prev and next links and also be auto numbered. this is the second problem I am trying to solve.
For the subpages I am thinking that a template on the first subpage with option split on the linkwrap would work for styling the prev and next links but I have no idea how to put the image for the current page in the middle.

Comment: can you show the output you get know, and what you want to get? Btw. why has special.items not "next | prev"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally solved all but one issue. which is to auto number the page. For those interested, you need to map the next and prev separately to so that you can put a page number button inbetween. The following typoscript code sits on the root page tree of the pages you want to setup browse buttons for:

```
    #Next page button setup
lib.nextpage = HMENU
lib.nextpage.special = browse
lib.nextpage.special.items = next

#can't remove the page title some reason it just gets inserted back so we set it to nothing
lib.nextpage.special.next.fields.title =

#if we're on the parent page of the page tree we wish to browse next should point to the first page of the subtree.
[globalVar = TSFE:id = 46]
  lib.nextpage.special.next.uid = 100
[global]  

lib.nextpage.1 = TMENU
lib.nextpage.1{
     noBlur = 1
     expAll = 0
     NO = 1
     #NO.ATagTitle = 1
     NO.linkWrap = <div class=nextLGMpg>|</div>

}

#Page number
lib.currpage = TEXT
#can't autonumber yet so put a 1 as a placeholder for the current page number 
lib.currpage.value = 1 
lib.currpage.wrap = <div id="currLGMpg">|</div>

#previous page button setup

#copy from next page setup; tbh all we gain is 1 less line code
lib.prevpage < lib.nextpage
lib.prevpage.special.items = prev
lib.prevpage.special.prev.fields.title =
#again if we're at the 1st subpage we need to target the parent page as that is page one.
[globalVar = TSFE:id = 100]
  lib.prevpage.special.prev.uid = 46
#next line tests to see if we're at page 1. If we are we remove the prev object because browsing stops here.
[globalVar = TSFE:id = 46]
lib.prevpage >
[global]

lib.prevpage.1 = TMENU
lib.prevpage.1{
     noBlur = 1
     expAll = 0
     NO = 1
     #NO.ATagTitle = 1
     NO.linkWrap = <div class=prevLGMpg>|</div>

}
```

Once I figure out how to autonumber I will update the answer.

Comment: You can use ``dataWrap = {debug:data}`` to see all relavant data. There should already be a register or a variable to cound the items which should get you the numbers.
Anyway, you can change the title of the links via ``HMENU.TMENU.NO.stdWrap.*lookitup*``.

Answer (score 2):

Hello for cycling you should follows the below steps this only for next please follow same steps for prev.

```
temp.lightbox_navi.30 = HMENU
temp.lightbox_navi.30 {
    stdWrap.wrap = <li>|</li>
    special = browse
    special {
        items = next
        items.prevnextToSection = 0
        next.fields.title = < next Projekt
    }
    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        NO = 1
    }
    stdWrap.ifEmpty.cObject = HMENU
    stdWrap.ifEmpty.cObject {
        special = browse
        special {
            items = first
            items.prevnextToSection = 0
            first.fields.title = < next Projekt o
        }
        1 = TMENU
        1 {
            NO = 1
        }
    }
}
```